# flutter riverpod: initialize state on notify provider

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I am using notifier provider like this :

```
@riverpod
class MainProductNew extends _$MainProductNew {
  @override
  AsyncValue<MainProductStateModel> build(String id) {
    return const AsyncValue.loading();
  }

  Future<void> getMainProduct() async {
    final result = await ref.watch(productViewNewRepositoryProvider).getMainProduct(id);

    state = AsyncValue.data(state.value!.copyWith(mainProductModel: result.extractDataOrThrow));
  }
}
```

When I am calling getMainProduct method and I want to update the state , since state value is null I get :

```
Error: Unexpected null value.
```

the issue is here :

```
state.value!.copyWith
```

MainProductStateModel is a freezed class, How can I correctly initialize the state?

Do I need to create an object if the state is null but after that I can use copywith, Is it correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if your state shoudl be AsyncLoading until a known future completes, return *that future*.  So your code should look like this:

```
@riverpod
class MainProductNew extends _$MainProductNew {
  @override
  Future<MainProductStateModel> build(String id) {
    return _getMainProduct();
  }

  Future<MainProductStateModel> _getMainProduct() async {
    final result = await ref.watch(productViewNewRepositoryProvider).getMainProduct(id);

    return result;
  }
}
```

I made it private to distinguish between internal functions and external mutation API methods.
And you could further simplify that internal function as:

```
  Future<MainProductStateModel> _getMainProduct() =>
    ref.watch(productViewNewRepositoryProvider).getMainProduct(id);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, Is it possible for the Async provider to change state? I mean async notifier is using Async value, I want to use my state.

Comment: Yes, you can use "state = " in your public mutator methods.